# @RawValue annotation is not applicable to target value parameter

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to `Parcelize` a data class.
It contains one parameter :

```
var tokenType: Any? = null
```

For this variable compiler complains at compile time that :

```
Type is not directly supported by Parcelize. 
Annotate the parameter with @RawValue if you want it to be serialized via 
writeValue()
```

Though the error is self-explanatory, when I add @RawValue like this:

```
@RawValue var tokenType: Any? = null
```

it gives an error :

```
This annotation is not applicable to the target value parameter
```

Any hints on how to handle this?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

I got the answer to this problem from `Kotlang` community.
Answer is you can not annotate the variable itself
but you have to annotate its type.

So annotating in the following way removes the error :

```
 var tokenType: @RawValue Any? = null
```

Though do not forget to write serilizer/deserializer for this property manually as it will not be done automatically.

Comment: After seeing this answer I immediately realised understood what target annotation meant, thank you!

Comment: How do you write the serilizer/deserializer for the Any type?

Comment: @Beast77 Please use normal writeToParcel and readFromParcel Methods for same as is used without Parcelize keyword.

Comment: @Tarun why would you use Parcelize for then?

Comment: still working...many thanks

Comment: You can add a link to the thread on `KotLang` to help others get more context.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/

Comment: Remember to add annotation @Serializable to object/class

Comment: `Though do not forget to write serilizer/deserializer for this property manually as it will not be done automatically.` - what do you mean exactly?