# How to parcel value with type Any? using @Parcelize

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable, parcel

I have encountered with a problem when trying to put value with type Any? into parcel. I'm using @Parcelize from kotlinx.android.parcel. Lint is warning me and hints with message to add `@RawValue`, but it's not helping. I got:

> android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when
>   unmarshalling

My data class:

```
@Parcelize
    data class FormulaNode(
            val term: @RawValue Any? = null,
            val operator: String? = null,
            val left: FormulaNode? = null,
            val right: FormulaNode? = null) : Parcelable
```

Comment: You cannot parcel anything which is not parcelable. So instead `Any` use `Parcelable`.

Comment: @tynn But I need something like Any, because `term` can be String or FormulaNode at the same time

Comment: @tynn Ok, I'll try this approach

Comment: @tynn It's not working in my case, but thanks for help

Comment: @Skullper got any solution ?

Comment: @JithishPN yup, I have started to put into parcel and get from it by my self, with several checks. This was only solution I found in my case

Comment: @Skullper please share referal links to do parcel  in kotlin ?

Comment: @JithishPN I have no links, it was my solution. You need to implement parcelable by yourself without `@Parcelize`.

Comment: @Skullper  got solution. if raw value(any) is custom class , implement custom class also Parcelable will solve the issue.

Answer (score 10):

Follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49606439/5857685

```kotlin
var tokenType: @RawValue Any? = null
```