# How to convert a JSON array of mixed types using moshi and kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, moshi

Iam unable to convert this Json, keep getting the following error: **com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at path**

```
{"summary": {
    "rows": [
    [
        "08 May, 2023",
        {
            "name": "some item name",
            "index": 0
        },
        "Test",
        "Test"
    ],
    [
        "09 May, 2023",
        {
            "name": "some other item name",
            "index": 0
        },
        "Test",
        "Test"
    ]
    ]

}
}
```

The only solution i got was using @RawValues

Comment: How's the class you defined to deserialize this json? Plus the json you provided is wrong formated...

Comment: data class Root(
    val summary: Summary,
)

data class Summary(
    val rows: List<List<Any?>>,
)

Comment: Please update the json so it's not malformed.

Comment: Have update it sorry didn't see it

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the two classes you have to create are :

```
data class Summary(val rows: List<List<Any>>)
data class Root(val summary: Summary)
```

Then to have the `Root` object from a `json` you have to create the adapter as follows

```
val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
val adapter = moshi.adapter(Root::class.java)
val root = adapter.fromJson(json)
```

### Edit

As the error message says

> Type is not directly supported by 'Parcelize'. Annotate the parameter type with '@RawValue

What it is saying is that not all types can be serialized using `Parcel`, and therefore cannot be used directly with `@Parcelize`, so that's why it recommends you to use `@RawValue`.

The `@RawValue` annotation is used to indicate that the annotated parameter should be treated as a raw value by the compiler. When used with `@Parcelize`, it tells the compiler to not generate any serialization or deserialization code for the annotated parameter.

You should add `@RawValue` to the attribute that is `Any`.

In your example

```
data class Summary(@RawValue val rows: List<List<Any>>)
```

Ref:

[How to parcel value with type any using parcelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53116682/how-to-parcel-value-with-type-any-using-parcelize)

[Rawvalue annotation is not applicable to target value parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49606163/rawvalue-annotation-is-not-applicable-to-target-value-parameter/49606439#49606439)

Comment: if i use **Any?** i get the following error: Type is not directly supported by 'Parcelize'. Annotate the parameter type with '@RawValue